# Recurly paginate all transactions

Tags: php, recurly

I can't get the pagination for the transaction list from Recurly to work properly, it always seem to return the entire list of transactions instead of just page 1 with 15 transactions.

My code:

```
<?php

try {
// Get all successful transactions
$transactions = Recurly_TransactionList::getSuccessful([ 'per_page' => 15, 'type' => 'purchase' ]);



foreach( $transactions as $transaction ){

    $first_name = $transaction->details[0]->billing_info->first_name;
    $last_name = $transaction->details[0]->billing_info->last_name;
    $address = $transaction->details[0]->billing_info->address1;
    $city = $transaction->details[0]->billing_info->city;
    $zip = $transaction->details[0]->billing_info->zip;
    $transaction_uuid = $transaction->uuid;
    $created_date = $transaction->created_at->format('Ymd');
    $subscription_uuid = $transaction->subscription->get()->uuid;

    var_dump($subscription_uuid);
}

} catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e);
} ?>
```

This should, according to the Recurly documentation (https://docs.recurly.com/api/transactions), return the first page with a list of 15 transactions. However when the script runs I get the entire list with every transaction.

I'm trying to create a page that contains 15 transactions with a button to go to the next page, is there anything I'm doing wrong or am I reading the documentation wrong?

Comment: The Recurly PHP client has some limitations with pagination, [see here](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-php/issues/31).

Comment: @rafiki_rafi Yeah I noticed that issue. I ended up having to create my own pagination functionality by modifying the PHP library a bit. I can't understand the reasoning of not providing proper pagination in the first place..